# Update Firestore document with ion-datetime value change

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

Having an `ion-datetime` element in a page, I would like to update its value in a Firestore document. I would like to use an elegant and easy to read and use solution, as its HTML tag events. I used its `onChange` event. But it triggers every time the page loads and its value (obviously) changes when the variable where it is linked is reassigned, due to the **unassigned** error that is thrown if I do not initialize it somewhere, such as the constructor.

I tried other things, but I am running out of ideas.

So, for showing the best part I did, for having you informed, it was:

```html
<ion-datetime
    display-format="D MMMM YYYY"
    [(ngModel)]="object.date"
    (onChange)="changeDate()">
</ion-datetime>
```

```
private docId: string;

constructor(private aRoute: ActivatedRoute, private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore) { }

ionViewWillEnter() { this.docId = this.aRoute.snapshot.paramMap.get('id'); }

private changeDate(): void {
    const partial: Partial<Type> = {date: this.object.date};
    this.angularFirestore.collection('type').doc<Type>(this.id).update(partial);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ionic framework you need to use `(ionChange)` instead of `(onChange)` in order for it to work.

However, you should avoid using it in your use case scenario, as it is always being triggered when a value is changed in `object.date` object as it is happening every time the page reloads. Basically you are telling him to save the value every time the event triggers. So the event can be triggered on pro grammatically changing the value of `object.date` or when user is changing it by selecting a different date. In each of the two ways the event will be triggered and the function will be called.

Use `[pickerOptions]` instead, as it is documented in [ion-datetime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/datetime) documentation. You can have custom buttons when selecting the date. So the function to update the date will be only called when the user click on the option.

## Working example:

### In HTML:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label possition="floating">Choose date:</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime
    display-format="D MMMM YYYY"
    [(ngModel)]="object.date"
    [pickerOptions]="customPickerOptions"> //Replaced this part (ionChange)=""
  </ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

### In TS:

```
  customPickerOptions: any;

  constructor() {

      this.customPickerOptions = {
        buttons: [{
          text: 'Save',
          handler: newTime => console.log("Saving date in Firestore ...");
        }]
      }

  }
```

BUT, `handler` has its own scope, so you will not be able to get the value as `this.object.date`, so take the response from `newTime` and save the data from there. You can get the number of the day as `newTime.day["text"]`, the number of the month as `newTime.month["text"]` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. That resulted very useful for me. I must say that even visiting the official docs I didn't see it until I read your answer. Also, your answer explained explained very well how it works. Cheers.