# Ionic 4 changes automatically date set via GUI (ion-datetime)

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

After posting [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58259917/update-firestore-document-with-ion-datetime-value-change) before, its answer was what I needed and works as I want, but I'm getting an unexpected behavior when setting the date from ion-datetime: The date I selected doesn't match the date it sets. Always adds one more month, and when I set the 31st day adds one day, changing month again. Is it normal?

If some information is needed for further understanding, this is how it remained:

```html
<ion-datetime displayFormat="D/M/YYYY" pickerFormat="D M YYYY"
  min="{{minDate.getFullYear()}}" max="{{minDate.getFullYear()+10}}"
  [(ngModel)]="object.limitDate" [pickerOptions]="customPickerOptions">
</ion-datetime>
```

```js
private customPickerOptions: any;

constructor(private angularFirestore: AngularFirestore) {
  this.customPickerOptions = {
    buttons: [{
      text: 'Cancelar',
      role: 'cancel'
    }, {
      text: 'Guardar',
      handler: (result: any) => {
        const date: string = new Date(result.year.value, result.month.value, result.day.value).toISOString();
        this.angularFirestore.collection('object').doc<ObjectType>(this.docId).update({ limitDate: date });
      }
    }]
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like Ionic uses the index range 1-12 for months.
Date object of javascript uses 0-11. So if you for example choose february in the datepicker you get 2 from ion-datetime which would be in javascript March (0,1,2).

Furthermore, by using new Date() javscript always applies the browsers/machines timezone to your passed date.

Edit:
I suggest you start using the MatMomentDateModule.
There you can define how your date should be displayed and how the date input should be parsed.
With momentjs you can freely handle timezones.